# C# Threading - Multiple threads spawned, only 1 or 2 are executing others waiting

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, execution

I've got this code below, where I spawn several threads, normally about 7, and join them to wait until all are done:

```
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            Thread thread;
            foreach (int size in _parameterCombinations.Keys)
            {
                thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CalculateResults));
                thread.Start(size);
                threads.Add(thread);
            }

            // wait for all threads to finish
            for (int index = 0; index < threads.Count; index++)
            {
                threads[index].Join();
            }
```

When I check this most of the time only one or two threads are running at the same time, only once or twice when I rerun the app all of them executed.

Is there any way to force all the threads to start executing?

Many thanks.

Comment: Since we don't know the definition of CalculateResults its hard to tell if this method blocks at some point, but that would explain the observed behavior.

Comment: how many cores are there on your machine? only so many threads can actually run in parallel.

Comment: How long does the calculation task takes?

Comment: luke, that's not correct. Threads can be executed and be frozen.

Comment: @luke: As Adibe pointed out, that's not correct. Even with a single core and no hyperthreading, the OS will give each thread its own slice.

Comment: Calculation task takes quite long, half an hour or so. It calls a long-running process in a loop, and then locks for a splitsecond to add an item to SorterList<T,T>. Thanks.

Comment: p.s. The process that's called in the loop is quite CPU-intensive, I must mention. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Please let us know what you mean by `running` - how are you determining which threads are `running`?

Comment: I fire the event like so from Calculate method, and append the thread # to the progressMessage:

 if (ProgressChanged != null)
                    {
                        ProgressChanged(new BLL.EventArgs.ProgressChangedEventArgs(progressPercentage, true, progressMessage));
                    }

By long-running I mean that it gets a large data set from DB and then goes through it in several nested loops. Each loop iteration takes a second to run and that's because it's all CPU work, like adding and comparing, etc, and not just waiting for outside response.

Comment: @Steven Sudit:  i assumed when he said that he only saw two threads running "at the same time" that he meant just that.  i understand that the os can schedule more threads/processes than there are cores/logical CPUs, but it can still only run so many things at the same actual time.

Comment: @luke: Hyperthreading makes that entirely ambiguous, as two threads are scheduled simultaneously on the same core and interleave whenever either one is momentarily blocked by a cache miss or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine.. i changed it abit to show you that the execution of the thread is not limited to 2 threads.
I would look for problems in the calculation process..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        Thread thread;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CalculateResults));
            thread.Start();
            threads.Add(thread);
        }

        // wait for all threads to finish
        for (int index = 0; index < threads.Count; index++)
        {
            threads[index].Join();
        }
    }

    static void CalculateResults(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread number " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " is alive");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread number " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " is closing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Adibe, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I replaced the call to my CPU intensive function with Thread.Sleep and it worked fine. The Calculate function consumes all of CPU and its difficult for the OS to switch threads I suspect.

Comment: @misha-r: Your calculation threads will be preempted and rescheduled by the OS as needed.